# Modify code before production build

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I need to replace static asset url endpoints for production, and I was wondering if there is anyway to do this before building for production.

Comment: Where do u have these URLs? Why not just use different configuration for prod and other environments?

Comment: You can have macros that read compilation flags and expand into different things depending on the values.

Comment: Don't use macros. Configuration files are designed for exactly this purpose.